# javascript closures getting variable out and wrong context

Tags: javascript

what is correct way of writing this in js?

notice `this.signals.total` is in a wrong context.

```
articleSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this.publisher) {
    this.publisher = this.url;
  }

  social.facebook(this.url, function(err, signals) {
   //problem is this
   this.signals.total = signals.total_count;
  });

  if (!this.weight) {
    this.weight = 1440;
  }

  var currentDate = new Date();
  this.updated_at = currentDate;
  if (!this.created_at) {
    this.created_at = currentDate;
  }

  next();
});
```

this in that case refers to `social.facebook` correct?

There are several ways I could deal with the problem, e.g. create outside variable, but what is js way?

Comment: `social.facebook correct?` - nope, depends how calling callback it can be _social_, _window_, or something else, like request or promisse object

Comment: @Bergi, i not sure that this duplicate, op not say what _this_ expected

Comment: Notice  that you probably don't need to assign the result to an outside variable anyway - you cannot use it outside right away, because [it's an asynchronous callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572).

Comment: @Grundy: Probably the same `this` as elsewhere in the function. But regardless, the duplicate should show how to bind *any* value to `this`.

Comment: @Bergi yes its true, how can I resolve this issue? saving async data?

Comment: @salivan: You cannot really, or at least not access the safe before the data appears there. Saving a promise for the data is usually the best approach.

Comment: @Bergi so I should read up on promises

Comment: Yes, that's never a mistake :-) I can recommend https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources as a good start, although you'll find many more tutorials these days (of varying quality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to store a reference to the correct context:

```
articleSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // ...

  var that = this; // Store a reference to `this`.
  social.facebook(this.url, function(err, signals) {
   // Use `that`.
   that.signals.total = signals.total_count;
  });

  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a common solution is to assign the `this` pointer to a variable outside the inner function like this:

```
var self = this;

function foo() {
  // this would not work, but self does
}
```

In ECMA-Script 6, you can also use an arrow function instead.

```
social.facebook(this.url, (err, signals) => {
   // this will point to the outer this
});
```

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) for more details:

Answer (score 0):

It is totally depends on how the callback is called.

1/ `this` will be global.

```
social.facebook = function(url, fn) {
  fn(url)
}
```

2/ `this` will be `social`

```
social.facebook = function(url, fn) {
  fn.call(this, url)
}
```

This way `this` can also be something weird:

```
social.facebook = function(url, fn) {
  fn.call(weirdObject, url)
}
```

Create outside variable like the others answer is one way, the other one is `bind`.

```
social.facebook(this.url, function(err, signals) {
  //problem is this
  this.signals.total = signals.total_count;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: `social.facebook` not an object, object is _social_, so second variant wrong